# How can you make a table with nested tables WCAG AA compliant

Tags: css, user-interface, accessibility, devexpress, wcag

Customers always want a UI looking table that has an expansion area to show a nested table of related-data.

I have done this with DIV tags and styles before but a table in the cell of the table would be easier.

From what I know of WCAG AA compliance, tables should only be used for tabular data and adding a nested table to a cell or even controls makes things confusing for screen readers and other to tools.

My question is simple, how can you make a table with nested tables or controls accessible?

For Example - the DevExpress Master-Detail View claims to be accessible.
https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/MasterDetailView/Angular/Light/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nested tables are perfectly fine if they're semantic.  I would ***not*** use the master-detail table example as your template.  It's pretty whacked out.  The code is overly complicated, incorrectly uses grid/gridcell instead of table/tablecell, and the screen reader has difficulty navigating to the nested table.

If you use a real `<table>` along with its associated `<tr>`, `<th scope="row/col">`, `<td>`, and `<caption>` then you can have one of the table cells (`<td>`) contain another `<table>`.

A screen reader user can use the <kbd>T</kbd> key to navigate to a table (if using JAWS or NVDA) and then <kbd>ctrl+alt+arrow</kbd> to navigate within the table.  Pressing <kbd>T</kbd> again will navigate to the nested table and the user can navigate within the nested table.  It all works great.

I would recommend using a `<caption>` so you can name your table and the screen reader user will know the purpose of the table.